# Session always returns null

Tags: php, session

I have my index.php page, which is where users can register and login. I want to display Welcome Admin once the user logs in. I have realized that session is null what can cause `$_SESSION` to become null?

```
<?php

session_start();

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=blog", "root", "");
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

$v = $db->prepare("select * from uyeler where uye_sifre=? and uye_ad=?");
var_dump($v);
if ($_POST) {

    $isim = $_POST["isim"];
    $sifre = $_POST["sifre"];

    $v->execute(array($sifre, $isim));
    $x = $v->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $d = $v->rowCount();


    if ($d) {
        $_SESSION["ad"] = $x["uye_ad"];
        $_SESSION["sife"] = $x["uye_sifre"];
        $_SESSION["durum"] = $x["uye_durum"];
        echo "Giriş başarılı";
    } else {
        echo "Geçersiz Kullanıcı";
    }

} else {
    if ($_SESSION) {
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        echo "adam üye";
    } else {

        echo '<form action="" method="post">


    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Uye Ad</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="isim" id=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Uye Şifre</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="sifre" id=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><input type="submit"  id=""></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>';
    }
}
?>
```

this is the var_dump output

```
wamp64\www\indeks.php:12:
object(PDOStatement)[2]
  public 'queryString' => string 'select * from uyeler where uye_sifre=? and uye_ad=?' (length=51)
C:\wamp64\www\indeks.php:34:
array (size=3)
  'ad' => null
  'sife' => null
  'durum' => null
```

Comment: What errors did you get when you checked your error log? The `$_SESSION` array would only be null if `session_start()` was not called before being used, or if it failed as the result of output started before headers could be set. In both both cases PHP will definitely give you a detailed error telling you everything you need to know to debug the issue. Sharing that error information would help narrow it down.

Comment: I updated the topic

Comment: The error is not the Session, it is the return of your query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run your query manually to see what your query returns.
2. `fetchAll` returns a multidimentional array. So fix these lines

   ```
   $_SESSION["ad"] = $x["uye_ad"];
   $_SESSION["sife"] = $x["uye_sifre"];
   $_SESSION["durum"] = $x["uye_durum"];
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   $_SESSION["ad"] = $x[0]["uye_ad"];
   $_SESSION["sife"] = $x[0]["uye_sifre"];
   $_SESSION["durum"] = $x[0]["uye_durum"];
   ```

   `$x` is an multidimensional and looks like this:

   ```
   $x = array(
   array('uye_ad'=>'any value', 'uye_sifre'=>'any value2', 'uye_durum'=>'any value3',)
   );
   ```

Comment: Because in this line `$x = $v->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` $x is an multidimensional array. It loos like this:

`array(array('uye_ad'=>'any value', 'uye_sifre'=>'any value2', 'uye_durum'=>'any value3',));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$v = $db->prepare("select * from uyeler where uye_sifre=:sifre and uye_ad=:isim");
$v->bindParam(':sifre', $sifre, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$v->bindParam(':isim', $isim, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$v->execute();
```

For more info, lookup [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: gives me this output     Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in